# Fetch and Update only 1 row sql

Tags: sql

Hi when i enter the data's all the data inside the table intBalance is updating. I don't know whats wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include('config.php');
$accname=$_POST['accname'];
$accnum=$_POST['accnum'];
$pin=$_POST['pin'];
$grandtotal=$_POST['grandtotal'];


$resultq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_bank_debit WHERE txtAccountNumber = '$accnum'");

            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultq))
            {
            $balance=$rows['intBalance'];
            //$pqs=$rows['qtysold'];
            //$left=$pql-$qty;
            //$solds=$pqs+$qty;
            $balupdate=$balance-$grandtotal;
            mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_bank_debit SET intBalance='$balupdate'");
            }


/*$resulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM athan_products WHERE id = '$id'");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resulta))
            {
            $pprice=$row['price'];
            $psize=$row['product_size_name'];
            }
$total=$pprice*$qty;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO orderdetails (customer, qty, price, total, partsname, size, transactioncode) VALUES('$memid', '$qty', '$pprice', '$total', '$name', '$psize', '$transcode')");
header("location: order.php");*/
?>
```

All intBalance in the table is updating :(

Comment: You need a where clause in your update query to specify which row to update

Comment: You forgot to specify, whom (which record) to update.. So the database updated everyone smartly!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query says: update the table `tbl_bank_debit` and set each occurence of 'intBalance' to the value in '$balupdate'.

Clearly, as TI states, you need a `where` clause to say: do not overwrite all, but just these.

Sample:

```
UPDATE tbl_bank_debit SET intBalance='$balupdate' where account = 123
```

Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) for more help